# Как отрендерить jsx компонент из строки на странице? выходит ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs

Как отрендерить jsx компонент из строки на странице? выходит ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';


export const renderComponentFromString = (componentString) => {
  const componentFunction = new Function('React', componentString);
  const MyComponent = componentFunction(React);
  const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('pek')!);

  root.render(MyComponent());
};

export function Home() {

  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {
    const jsx = `const UserList = () => { const [state, setState] = useState(0) 
    return <div> <p onClick={setState((prev) => prev + 1)}>{state}</p></div>}`
    renderComponentFromString(jsx)
  }, [])

  return (
      <div id='pek'>
        <button onClick={handleOnClick}>RUN</button>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Если кратко, нельзя в js запихнуть jsx компонент.  `new Function` это создание js функции, а не реакт компонента

Comment: @SwaD как можно создать реакт компонент?

Comment: Что именно вы хотите сделать этим? Что должно происходить по нажатию на кнопку?

Comment: @SwaD монтирование компонента в страницу

Comment: По клику что бы повился новый компонет? Где? Вместо старого? Рядом с текущей кнопкой?

Comment: @SwaD рядом с кнопкой, в диве с id = pek